# Columns and floating images and their white spaces

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, css-float, gallery

There is 3 columns sized 33% each, with images inside each of them (each image has a different height). On a device sized like the iPad, I want to change the size of each column to be 50% - now when I do that, the third column appears in the middle buttom of the top two column - and it looks very weird.

So I tried to make the the third column to be sized as 100% and the images inside this column to be sized as 50% - This worked! However the problem is as it shown on the image below:

The red is column 1, the blue is column 2, the black is column 3, and the yellow highlight is the space created.

[image]
How do I get rid of that space?

Here is a fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Vhrnr please note i am only showing you the code as it's not allowing me to paste it here for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have a rogue div somewhere in your code (possible near column3). If you could paste a code snippet or a working Fiddle link it would definitely help.

Comment: Here is a link to a fiddle, jsfiddle.net/Vhrnr